# jQuery HTML Button fires function multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

I'm creating an HTML form that displays a column of checkboxes, click on submit and the event will be picked up by a jQuery function. However, after examining the function in the Firebug net panel, I've noticed that the function fires multiple times even if I click the button just once! Any idea why?

HTML:

```
echo "<form id='massHoursSubtraction'>";
echo "How many hours to subtract? <input type='text' name='hours'><br />";
$entries = 1;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($members)) {
    $studentID = $row['studentid'];
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='studentID[]' id='' value='$studentID'>$studentID";
    echo "<br />";
    $entries++;
}
echo "<input type='button' id='submitValues' value='Submit' onclick='javascript:getHours($entries);' />";
echo "</form>";
```

Javascript:

```
function getHours(numberOfEntries) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitValues").click(function(){
        var str = $("#massHoursSubtraction").serialize();
        alert("How many times?");           
        $.post("output.php", str);                                  
    });
});
}
```

Here's a screenshot of the Firebug net panel: http://imgur.com/Z83s5fr
This is the `$_POST` string: `hours=1&studentID%5B%5D=5112244`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have both an `onclick` attribute on the button and in your jQuery you then *register* the click event. So, every time you click the button, you add at least one more listener to the click event. First click, you add it once, second time, you add it another 2 times for a total of 4, this time, however the handler will actually fire (it doesn't first time as it is registering).

Remove the `onclick` attribute from the button and remove the function altogether so you only have:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submitValues").click(function(){
        var str = $("#massHoursSubtraction").serialize();
        alert("How many times?");           
        $.post("output.php", str);                                  
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

That is because every time you click on the element `submitValues` it attaches a click handler there. That is where your extra events are coming from. You should instead just do this:

```
echo "<input type='button' id='submitValues' value='Submit' />"
```

and then attach your event handler once when document.ready is issued here:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#submitValues").click(function(){
    var str = $("#massHoursSubtraction").serialize();
    alert("How many times?");           
    $.post("output.php", str);                                  
 });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the following line inside the function you are calling

```
$("#IdofButton").removeAttr('onclick');
```

This will remove the click function of the button, so it cannot fire the function multiple times.